# include in makefile ignore variable overload

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

To ignore variable overriding when I include some file, I use this construction :

```
.PHONY: test
.SILENT:

include var/make/.env

var/make/.env: .env | var/make
    sed 's/=/?=/' $< > $@

var/make:
    mkdir -p $@

test:
    echo $(FOO)
```

Assuming my .env looks like this:

```sh
FOO=BAR
```

My sourced file will look like this:

```sh
FOO?=BAR
```

So that FOO is only written if it is not defined ; never overloaded :

```sh
$ make test
BAR
$ FOO=BAZ make test
BAZ
```

Is there a proper way of doing this ?

Comment: What are you allowed to change? Can you use `make FOO=BAZ test` instead of `FOO=BAZ make test`?

Comment: I can do export FOO=BAZ; make test as well ; Idk the limits of shell syntax for variable definition within command call